# Mvc 3 Action signature

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to get the action arguments signature when overriding OnActionExecuting to match between the client sent parameter types to the wanted action parameter types?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first by checking by name with filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("myParameter"), and then attempting to use the "as" keyword to see if it matches the type.